# How To Send Command Lines Variables to PRNQCTL.VBS

Tags: variables, vbscript, passwords, set

I want to be able to send the username and password over to the `prnqctl` script.
I know what I have below does not work. **Returning subscript out of range error.**
But how do I get something like this over to `prnqctl.vbs`. I don't want to hard-code the username and password as they can change or expire.

```
set /p USR =Username:
set /p PAS =Password: 

cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnqctl.vbs -x -s SERVER01 -p PRINTER01 -u Domain\ %USR% -w %PAS%
```

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces included in the name of the variable

```
set /p USR =Username:
set /p PAS =Password: 
          ^............This space is included in the variable name
```

So, you have variables named `%USR %` and `%PAS %`. Remove the spaces to solve the problem